# Proof of the following combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Prove

$$\sum_{m\le i\le k-l} \binom{k-i-1}{l-1} \binom{i-1}{m-1} = \binom{k-1}{m+l-1}$$

where $m$, $l$, $i$, $k$ are positive integers and $k\ge m+l$.

---

*Is this related to [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)?*

Comment: idk, induction+pascal's identity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we  have   *[Chu-Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=m}^{k-l}}&\color{blue}{\binom{k-i-1}{l-1}\binom{i-1}{m-1}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-l-m}\binom{k-i-m-1}{l-1}\binom{i+m-1}{i}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-l-m}\binom{k-i-m-1}{k-l-m-i}\binom{-m}{i}(-1)^i\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-l-m}\binom{-l}{k-l-m-i}(-1)^{k-m-l}\binom{-m}{i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{-l-m}{k-l-m}(-1)^{k-m-l}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{k-1}{m+l-1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index to start with $i=0$. We also use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and again $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we use again $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we apply *[Chu-Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.
- In (5) we use once more $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.